# How to find out if an installed Eclipse is 32 or 64 bit version?

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, 32bit-64bit

How can I find out if a specific Eclipse instance on my (Windows 7) PC is the 32-bit or 64-bit version?

I've checked the About screen and the maze of dialogs one can call from there, but I didn't find any clues.

Also, right-clicking eclipse.exe in Windows explorer and opening the properties dialog box didn't give any hints.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to open the Windows Task manager and switch to the processes tab.

32-bit programs should be marked with `*32`.

Comment: Or hit Ctrl+Shift+ESC to launch Task Manager quicker.

Comment: only if you are a windows user.

Comment: If you can't open Eclipse search alternate answers below for eclipse.ini

Comment: @Gab - the question was referring to windows.

Comment: -1 because this assumes you can load eclipse, see answer below.

Comment: @Kidburla - I'm a little surprised at how popular this question has gotten over the years.  However, if you look at the original question, he was clearly able to open eclipse.

Answer (score 151):

Open `eclipse.ini` in the installation directory, and observe the line with text:

plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.***x86_64***_1.0.200.v20090519
then it is **64** bit.

If it would be plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.***x86_32***_1.0.200.v20090519 then it is **32** bit.

Comment: If your installation is 64-bit the string **x86_** (which identifies a 32-bit installation) will still match. You need to look for **x86_64_**

Comment: how does that tell me I have 64 bit vs 32 bit?

Comment: @tatmanblue read string again, if u have basic knowledge of 32 and 64 bit, you will come know definitely :)

Comment: so what is the answer? which string is 32 and which is 64?

Answer (score 64):

Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> tab Configuration

Look for `-arch`, and below it you'll see either `x86_64` (meaning 64bit) or `x86` (meaning 32bit).

Comment: Though OP asked for Windows platform, this answer is OS independent: works for both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 23):

In **Linux**, run *file* on the Eclipse executable, like this:

```
$ file /usr/bin/eclipse
eclipse: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.4.0, not stripped
```

Answer (score 8):

Go to the Eclipse base folder → open eclipse.ini → you will find the below line at line no 4:

plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807

As you can see, line 1 is of 64-bit Eclipse. It contains x86_64 and line 2 is of 32-bit Eclipse. It contains x_86.

For 32-bit Eclipse only x86 will be present and for 64-bit Eclipse x86_64 will be present.