# Identify the bit version of installed eclipse 

Tags: java, eclipse, 32bit-64bit

I want to know the bit type of eclipse installed on my machine whether it is of 32 bit or 64 bit version as i need a function in java which return the bit version of eclipse.

thanks

Comment: Huh?  Please rephrase your question: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: More to explain: I have a program which does not work in 64 bit version of eclipse and it needs another snippet of code so i want to put a check whether eclipse is of 32 bit version or 64 bit version.

Comment: Java is meant to be architecture-independent: it should work exactly the same on 32-bit or 64-bit architectures.  (If you're using native functions or something extremely complex, it might be a different story, but this seems unlikely.)

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103366/how-to-find-out-if-an-installed-eclipse-is-32-or-64-bit-version

Answer (score 2):

You can check it from **eclipse.ini** file present in eclipse Home directory.

**Example:**

> if --launcher.library
>   plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_***64****1.1.200.v20130521-0416
>   then it is 64 bit and if --launcher.library
>   plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86****32***_1.1.200.v20130521-0416
>   then it is 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

There is also an Eclipse API for that.

You will need to add `org.eclipse.core.runtime` dependency into your plugin and then in `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform` class there is a static method `getOSArch()` that returns the current system architecture. You can compare it to the constants defined in the same class (e.g. `ARCH_X86_64` or `ARCH_X86`).

As stated in the javadoc it will default to `java.lang.System.getProperty("os.arch")` if the architecture is not specified on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this program is going to run *within* Eclipse (e.g. is a plugin), then there will be a number of properties in the System Properties object that will tell you this.  For instance:

- java.vm.name contains the name of the current JVM which (for Hotspot at least) includes "32-Bit" or "64-Bit".
- org.osgi.framework.processor tells you the "the Framework host-computer's processor name", which on my Eclipse is "x86-64".
- osgi.arch tells you the "platform architecture" which on my Eclipse is "x86-64".

Now it is not entirely clear what the last two mean, so you should probably do some experiments.

---

If you need to do this externally to Eclipse, then you could try running the Linux / Unix "file" command on the Eclipse executable and picking apart the resulting string.

Comment: I have got these two org.osgi.framework.processor and osgi.arch in help->about>installation detail-> configuration, but how i can read these information through programming.

Comment: I think they should have been added to the System Properties object.

Answer (score 0):

finally i  think for plugin purpose `System.getProperty("osgi.arch")` is perfect it returns x86 for 32 bit eclipse and x86_64 for 64 bit eclipse.

Comment: here dependency will be on your plugin.