# Eclipse reported "Failed to load JNI shared library"

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface

I can't open Eclipse because I get an alert that says

> Failed to load JNI shared library C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll

I've found a kind of solution on YouTube, *[Eclipse Failed to load JNI library fix](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPiOD5V74nk)*.

He says that you only have to download a [JRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine#Execution_environment) 7 folder. Then I just have to replace
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\server\jvm.dll` with `C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll`.

But where is the JRE 7 link?

Comment: Dont forget to delete the %temp% folder as well.

Comment: Probably it's happening because of jre and eclipse version (32/64 bit) mismatch. Go to configuration folder of eclipse setup and see log files for exact reason.

Comment: check your path environment variable that you include 32 bit jdk

Comment: Eclipse seems to depend on the PATH in Windows, and I had an Spss one first and "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" was missing.

Answer (score 196):

First, ensure that your version of Eclipse and JDK match, either both 64-bit or both 32-bit (you can't mix-and-match 32-bit with 64-bit).

Second, the -vm argument in `eclipse.ini` should point to the java executable. See 
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini for examples.

If you're unsure of what version (64-bit or 32-bit) of Eclipse you have installed, you can determine that a few different ways. See [How to find out if an installed Eclipse is 32 or 64 bit version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103366/how-to-find-out-if-an-installed-eclipse-is-32-or-64-bit-version)

Comment: Copy jre folder from this path "C:\Program Files\jre"

Comment: 64bit java 32bit eclipse was the problem for me.

Comment: The -vm argument solved it for me.

Comment: 32 bit java and 64 bit eclipse was the problem for me

Comment: You would think it could detect this and give a more helpful error message.

Comment: My problem was that, after I realized that I'm missing Java, I downloaded the Java auto-installer from my 32bit browser, so Java thought it should install 32bit version.

Comment: installing Java 64bit and updating the path environment variable to point to the new 64bit installation worked for me!

Comment: How to know how many bit Eclipse  is installed?

Comment: @gstackoverflow, I updated the answer with some help on that.

Comment: 34 bit java and 62 bit eclipse was the problem for me.

Comment: SOLUTION, DONT MIX 32 BIT AND 64 BIT EXECUTABLES

Answer (score 66):

Installing a 64-bit version of Java will solve the issue. Go to page *[Java Downloads for All Operating Systems](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp)*

This is a problem due to the incompatibility of the Java version and the Eclipse version
both should be 64 bit if you are using a 64-bit system.

Comment: The solution in that video didn't work for me..

Comment: I had already 64 bit version with same problem. Re-installing/updating solved it too.

Comment: This did not fix it for me. 32 bit java, 32 bit eclipse, 64 bit W7.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem in my case. Also i set jdk\bin path in PATH variable instead of jre\bin to get it work.

Answer (score 18):

Yep, in Windows 7 64 bit you have `C:\Program Files` and `C:\Program Files (x86)`. You can find Java folders in both of them, but you must add `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin` to environment variable PATH.

Comment: Moreover, you can have multiple versions of Java (on all platforms) and have forgotten, so make sure the system only sees one of them. I just go

Answer (score 10):

[JRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine#Execution_environment) 7 is probably installed in `Program Files\Java` and NOT `Program Files(x86)\Java`.

Comment: This presumes an English version of Windows.