# 32-bit linux based eclipse giving error on startup in Fedora 12

Tags: linux, eclipse, fedora

I downloaded the 32-bit eclipse for my 32-bit fedora 12. I extracted the tar.gz without any error. But when i click on the eclipse executable, i am getting the error:

"Failed to load the JNI shared library "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre/bin/../lib/i386/client/libjvm.so"
"

I am not able to resolve this error. Please inform how to proceed.

Regards,

Comment: Eclipse needs Java.  Do you have OpenJDK installed?  Do you have a "/usr/lib/jvm" directory with the above file in it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585135/eclipse-failed-to-load-jni-shared-library+

Answer (score 1):

Go to your eclipse folder 
Open `eclipse.ini` file and check if there is `-vm` option set properly 
Else set `-vm` in one line followed by your `jdk` installed `bin` folder. 
Hope this helps yo solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest avoiding OpenJDK, as Eclipse will keep complaining about it.
So, navigate to http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp and download appropriate Sun's Java package (32 or 64 bit, depending on your current installation). As Fedora uses RPMs for package management, I advise to use that method.

Then, after installation, run java -version in terminal, you should get something like:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode, sharing)
```