# Error While installing Android Adt Bundle with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have windows 7 64 bit.
I have installed jdk 7.I am trying to install the Android ADT bundle with eclipse.
But when i click the eclipse application installer.It is showing me a message

Failed to load the JNI shared library

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585135/eclipse-failed-to-load-jni-shared-library), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk)

Comment: [System requirements](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) say JDK6. Not sure if that could be your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install JDK6 first. Then try to install ADT

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
64-bit Java/JDK
64-bit Eclipse
64-bit OS
```

Hope it will help.