# Eclipse-Failed to load the JNI shared library

Tags: eclipse-juno

I downloaded `eclipse-juno`, and run it. It was giving error as " A `Java Runtime Environment` (JRE) or `Java Development Kit` (JDK) must be available in order to run `Eclipse`. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations:

```
C:\Program Files\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe javaw.exe in your current PATH "
```

Then I set environment variables as told in this post 
Eclipse - no Java (JRE) / (JDK) … no virtual machine.

Now its giving error
`Failed to load the JNI shered library "C\Program Files\Java\Jdk version\bin\...\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll"`

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure your Java and Eclipse have the same architecture - they **both** have to be either 32-bit or 64-bit. If that checks out, it should be OK.

I had the same problem: in my case everything was in fact 64-bit - 64-bit OS, 64-bit Eclipse and 64-bit JRE in use, so there was some confusion as to the origins of the issue...

What helped was correcting environmental variables JAVA_HOME and PATH - and pointing them directly to the bin catalogue:

```
.../My/Java/Location/bin
```

instead of

```
.../My/Java/Location
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you have installed wrong BIT version of Java on your machine. If your machine is 64 bit, you might have installed 32 bit java only. You can able to view whats your machine architecture by right clicking on computer and say properties.

If your machine is 64 bit machine. Install `64 bit Java, 64 bit Eclipse`. Make sure your classpath is set

Hope this will help.

Comment: Check this out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Answer (score 0):

You can test this solution, maybe works: go to `window->preference->server->runtime environments->and set your server path` **Example**: `tomcat path`.

for set java invironment variable and classpath:try like this:
[image]

and in path section:
[image]

check this link:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585135/eclipse-failed-to-load-jni-shared-library)

Comment: but I am not using servers yet. I jst want the eclipse to open first.

Comment: have you install jdk and jre in your system?and define their environment variables?