# Eclipse - Failed to load the JNI shared library

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, java-native-interface

Every time I try to start Eclipse, it says

> Failed to load the JNI shared libraby
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll"

I have no clue why this happens, because I reinstalled JDK, JRE and Eclipse multiple times. All the 64 bit version (I've got Windows 7 64 bit)

Comment: Something is not 64 bit if it is looking in `Program Files (x86)`.

Comment: Have you tried the answers in these links: [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585135/eclipse-reported-failed-to-load-jni-shared-library)

Comment: you most likely have wrong version of java installed like `jdk-7u51-windows-i586` if you are trying to install 64 the name of downloaded file shold be like `jdk-7u51-windows-x64`

Comment: however for some reason getting it to download right is also an issue...1st time you download its 64mb and broken, 2nd time like 12 mb..and finally 4th time it was 125mb..??

Comment: Thanks for this question. Solved my query at crucial time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, it somehow worked using the 32 Bit version of Eclipse...

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed all 64 bit version of Eclipse and JDK, you can check your system environment variable. Probably you set on old JAVA_HOME path pointing to

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: in my case everything was in fact 64-bit - 64-bit OS, 64-bit Eclipse and 64-bit JRE in use, so there was some confusion as to the origins of the issue...

What helped was correcting environmental variables JAVA_HOME and PATH - and pointing them directly to

```
.../My/Java/Location/bin
```

instead of

```
.../My/Java/Location
```

Answer (score 0):

If eclipse is 32bit
then, eclipse.ini file
 specify -vm C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre\bin\javaw.exe

If eclipse is 64bit
then, eclipse.ini file
 specify -vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\jre\bin\javaw.exe

Summary: specify compatible java version path ( 32 bit or 64 bit ).
-vm %JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\javaw.exe

Answer (score -1):

Just try to [download](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) this if you have 64 bit OS windows.Hope it will work :)