# Not able to start Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse

I have downloaded Eclipse Kepler and not able to start, when i tried to open(start eclipse) i got Error:
"**Failed to load C:/Java/..../bin/client/jvm.dll**" , after trying to find to solution i tried with adding 
"-vm C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javaw.exe " in eclipse.ini file, but for my bad luck even after adding this i got another error:
"**Java was started but returned exit code=13 
........**"

My Environment setup is:
Windows 8
Java 7, 64 bit
Eclipse Kepler 64 bit

Comment: This looks like a good question for http://superuser.com.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585135/eclipse-reported-failed-to-load-jni-shared-library

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you download:

- 64-bit version of Eclipse.
- 64-bit version of JDK.

Comment: Thanks, It was completely my mistake was having 32 bit java. Issue got resolved after having 64 bit java

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the following:

1) Your eclipse version,whether it is compatible with what version of java. Have that.
2) check if the the environment variable JAVA_HOME setted to your last version of java installed