# How to open my eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

when I open my eclipse ,it's warning that Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\client\jvm.dll"

what can I do ?thanks.
the download url is http://dl.oschina.net/action/soft/download?md5=b1e922422321f13070d0ade3327f56d8&soft=1466&t=12fa00cc04a35c8e7023503df6e9602a47dc4a44.
The version is Eclipse 4.4.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7385128/1237175

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585135/eclipse-reported-failed-to-load-jni-shared-library?rq=1) link

Comment: oh thanks,it's my fault!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to load the JNI shared Library (JDK)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When jvm.dll file is missing that means you probably deleted it. Try to restore it if it still in recycle bin. The other case is some jvm.dll errors could be related to a virus or other infection which means that you have to run scan for viruses.The best thing you can do for me is to uninstall you current Eclipse versions and download **The official** one from [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-standard-44/lunar). I check your link that you posted in, but when I open it I can see you some asian symbols.