# Updating the PATH Environment Variable stops Eclipse working

Tags: java, eclipse, java-5

To set up the `JDK`, I have added the following to the PATH environment variable in `Windows`.

```
C:\app\A_McLeod\product\11.2.0\client_1\jdk\bin
```

The problem is that Eclipse no longer opens and I get the error;

```
Failed to load the JNI shared library
"C:\app\A_McLeod\product\11.2.0\client_1\jdk\bin..\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll".
```

How can i get both `Eclipse` and the `JDK` working simultaneously?

Comment: which version are u using ?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your version of Eclipse and JDK match, either both 64-bit or both 32-bit (you can't mix-and-match 32-bit with 64-bit). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585135/eclipse-reported-failed-to-load-jni-shared-library)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit eclipse.ini and set the -vm  to the java executable you want to use