# I updated java and eclipse does not work

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I updated my JRE today 23.06.2012, and after that eclipse will no longer start.  When I double click to start up eclipse the splash screen appears like a camera flash and then nothing happens.

Any ideas as to how to fix this?

Comment: its a bit hard to say without any additional infos, but I would try to arbitrary set the new VM on eclipse ini (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini).

Comment: Although it's off-topic for *this* site, please remember always to add version names and numbers of you operating system, your eclipse and your previous and actual JRE. Help *us* to help *you* :)

Comment: Unzip a new elipse and use a fresh workspace

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is what worked for me:
Remove the lines:

```
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
```

Add these two lines:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\javaw.exe
```

Edit the path to match your installation.
The ini file is generally present at `$ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse.ini`
[Eclipse ini file](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)

Note: You'll need to change windows security settings to get access. I recommend you don't edit this type of file in notepad (use notepad++). Backup the file before you edit.

Comment: Everbody said that u only have to add the path but that alone didn't worked for me then I have to remove                                                          -vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 and now it works.

Comment: Thanks for posting this!  This one had me stumped.

Comment: The file in question is eclipse.ini

Comment: @PrinceVijayPratap Yes, you have to remove the version which is not present in your system anymore.

Answer (score 13):

I just added this line to the eclipse.ini file

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\javaw.exe
```

[The solution on my blog](http://mobappsdevnotes.blogspot.com/2012/06/i-updated-java-and-eclipse-does-not.html)
and it is now running successfully.

Answer (score 4):

check if the java\bin path is added in the path and inside the eclipse installation folder, there is a file called eclipse.ini and check if the vmargs are added like below.

```
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: I changed it to 1.4.0_03 and there is no actions 
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03

Comment: do you mean that when you change to 1.4.0_03 your eclipse starts correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Verify if you have installed a different version of JDK/JRE from your Eclipse. If you have installed 64 bits JDK version and your Eclipse version is 32 bits, it won't work. They have to be equal.

To verify what is your java version, type at command line window:

```
java -d64 -version
```

If appears: "Error: This Java instance does not support a 64-bit JVM. Please install the desired version.", it means that your java version is 32 bits.

To verify what is your Eclipse version, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103366/how-to-find-out-if-an-installed-eclipse-is-32-or-64-bit-version).

Comment: This was my case - it seems, that my 64-bit installation was updated by updater to 32-bit version :-/

Answer (score 1):

Right way is to replace following lines:

```
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
```

with following two lines:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\javaw.exe
```

You must edit the path to match your installation.

Even this is not enough. You must delete '.metadata' folder from your workspace.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same challenge after i updated from java . After searching the web. I used this simple solution.
 Find your eclipse installation direction. Mine was under C:\Users\adefemi\eclipse\jee-neon\eclipse

Then open ecliipse.ini,  go to the line that looks like this one
C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_144/bin

Change the version name accordingly. For instance mine was previously
C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin

That was all i had to do and eclipse started opening again.

Answer (score 0):

check your JAVA_HOME environment variable. Does it point to the new location.
Also see log file generated as a result of the crash

Comment: There is no crash log file in my eclipse folder

Answer (score 0):

If facing problem with Eclipse regarding java, do a manual installation of Java on your machine ( http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp ).

If you are using 64bit machine then you need to install java to `c:\program files\java (Default Path)` instead of `c:\program files (x86)\java`.

Set the environment variable path to `c:\program files\java\bin;`

And this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

USING THE LATEST JAVA UPDATE TOOL.

Let say you updated thru http://java.com/en/download/installed8.jsp then you just ran down thru the update process of Java and just next next the update process of Java then opening up eclipse you encountered the same issue here.

To fix this go to Environment Variables of Windows and check the "Path" variable you could notice that the Java update process added an entry similarly like this "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" remove this and add "JAVA_HOME" if you have one or the location of your Java. Also note that you must enter at the start of the "Path" environment.

This happens to me and removing the added entry of Java update resolve the issue and adding also the -vm and path of the Java in the eclipse.ini.

{Sorry don't have any screenshots to prove it}

Answer (score 0):

Once Java updates are installed on your machine edit the `eclipse.ini` file to update the latest jdk location.

In MacOS,

1. Right click on Eclipse App icon.
2. Click `Show Package Contents`.
3. Go to `Contents/Eclipse`.
4. Open `eclipse.ini` file.
5. Edit the `-vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin` to point to the latest.
6. Save and close `eclipse.ini`.

Now start Eclipse application and the error got fixed.