# MyEclipse crashes after running for several minutes (java was started but return exit code -1073741819)

Tags: java, eclipse

I have tried the following ways but they all do not work.

1. Reinstall MyEclipse
2. Reinstall java
3. Use Eclipse
4. Update java to 1.8.0_71
5. Use short format of directory in the JDK path

Both my java and MyEclipse are 64bit. H: is not a network driver.

[This is my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oXQn.png)

---

The following part is MyEclipse.ini

-startup

../Common/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar

--launcher.library

../Common/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.i18n.win32.win32.x86_64_4.2.0.v201201111650

-install

H:\MyE\MyEclipse 10

-vm

C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_71\bin\javaw.exe

-configuration

H:\MyE\MyEclipse 10\configuration

-vmargs

-Xmx512m

-XX:MaxPermSize=256m

-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m

-Dosgi.nls.warnings=ignore

Comment: Is your Java current ? What happens with Java 8 ?

Comment: Please execute this command `java -version` and tell us the output.

Comment: I have tried both java 7 and java 8, but neither of them works.

Comment: The output of "java - version" is java version "1.8.0_66" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b18),     Java Hotspot(TM) 64 bit server VM(build 25.66-b18, mixed mode)

Comment: What happens if you force Eclipse not to use javaw from C:\windows\system32 and reference a JDK / JRE directly ? And what is that `-java H:\...` stuff ? Try to remove it, especially the Unicode part could cause problems. And you should shorten your paths. Use "C:\dev\eclipse" or something shorter, not that lengthy path we can see in your screenshot

Comment: Please concentrate on one of the IDEs first and show us the .ini file of that. And provide the exact path where your javaw is available (`dir C:\javaw.exe /s /b` will do, repeat for every drive you use).

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner, can you explain specifically how to force Eclipse reference JDK directly? And I used a short path when I install MyEclipse, just as shown in the second screenshot.

Comment: Following your instructions, I found the exact path :C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\javaw.exe@Marged

Comment: And I uploaded the screenshot of myeclipse.ini. It's in the link under the first screen shot@Marged

Comment: Please provide the .ini as text, not as a screenshot. The search engine is not able to search images. The `-vm ` parameter tells Eclipse which JRE to use, in your case it is in a strange path and seems to be outdated. Change it so that it points to your 1.8.0_66 JRE. In addition to this it is a good idea to prevent spaces in directories, you can use `dir /x` to find out the short path without spaces, for `dir C:\prog* /X` it will likely tell you that `C:\Program Files` can be shortened to `C:\Progra~1`. One more thing: if H: is a network drive don't run any java stuff from it (bad performance)

Comment: @Marged  I have changed "Installed JREs" in MyEclipse and made it point to my jre but the error is still the same as the previous one. And I tried to set the directory without spaces but it seems it's not right on my computer (with the error "The home directory does not exist")

Comment: -1073741819 might be a file system error. Consider running checkdisk or something comparable.

Comment: _Please_ post the updated and simplified INI and switch to a local drive

Comment: You are to change the INI, setting up the installed JREs is something different

Comment: There are multiple steps to follow, you can see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39075801/2481005

Comment: I had  same  issue  when Eclipse  was  using  java  from  Program Files  but  JAVA_HOME for  maven  and  for  Debug  was  on another  drive(though  same  version).  After  I changed  eclipse ini  file  to  point  to  same  version  used  by  JAVA_HOME  it  was  not  crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Run the java update.  I was having the same issue and pulling my hair out.  There is an update today to Java 1.8.0_71 and now my Eclipse has not crashed.

***fingers crossed***

It has been open for like 4 minutes now :)

Comment: try running eclipse from the command line with 'eclipse -clean' and see if that helps.  also try to delete the '.metadata' folder in your workspace

Answer (score 0):

Right way is to replace following lines:

-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5

With following two lines

-vm
C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\javaw.exe

*You must edit the path to match your installation.*

Even this is not enough. You must delete '.metadata' folder from your workspace.