# Eclipse jvm.dll error when loading

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, path

Trying to open Eclipse after a couple of months and get this error:

[image: Eclipse Error]

So I checked that folder to see if it existed, and it did:

[image: JVM.dll]

I checked my PATH Was correct and it was also correct:

[image: Computer PATH]

When this error first occurred I had 3 Java installations. JRE 7 Update 10, JDK 7 Update 7 32bit and 64 bit.

I uninstall ALL and restarted my machine. Eclipse then stated, as expected that I needed a JRE or a JDK. So I downloaded and installed the latest JDK and now I get this error, despite everything appearing to be correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of eclipse did you download the x86 or the 64 ?

Comment: is there a way to find out without opening it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103366/how-to-find-out-if-an-installed-eclipse-is-32-or-64-bit-version

Comment: I did think I may need the 64 bit JDK too but haven't tested that yet

Comment: thanks Amine, that looks like it'll be the issue. I can't mark your answer as correct so if you reply as an official answer I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As requested in the comments.

Your eclipse version is searching for the x86 version of the jdk (You probably set this value when eclipse started). You should check if your eclipse is a 64 bit version if not, switch to a 64bits jvm.

Answer (score 2):

the problem lies with compatibility issue of jdd 6 with eclipse.I tried jdk 7 and it worked perfectly.Here is a link for jdk 7 downloading
http://download.cnet.com/Java-Development-Kit-64-Bit/3000-2218_4-75317068.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the Eclipse version. I faced the exact same problem, I was using Eclipse helios. I switched to Eclipse Kepler 64 bit and it is now working perfectly on my system. Even if the eclipse is 64 bit, some versions may not be compatible with other softwares using the same Java path (Eg: Oracle BI Publisher). Make sure to use the version compatible with others.

Answer (score 2):

### FIX for :: jvm.dll file missing issue while you open eclipse

This issue appears because of (64 or 32 bit) version conflict/mismatch happens between

1. installed OS,
2. Java(JDK)version and
3. eclipse version.

I got this issue and fixed it in this way.by adding the below argument (64 bit Java(JDK) path) in eclipse.ini.

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin
```

### My environment,details below

1. Mine is windows-7 64bit OS,
2. Java(JDK) 64 bit (so path specified in eclipse.ini)
3. Eclipse 64 bit(never confuse the eclipse version as 32 bit by seeing the win32.x86, see the later _64) i.e I use eclipse version below.

org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_**64**_1.1.500.v20170511-1520

You can see your eclipse version in eclipse.ini file.

Note:

I have another Eclipse (plugin tool) installed in my machine, which had the same issue, was expecting 32 bit Java(JDK), After I fixed the issue by setting the path for 32bit Java1.8 in environment variables, the primary eclipse stopped working.

So I set 64bit Java1.8 path in eclipse.ini.

Now both eclipse.exe and my plugintool eclipse working fine.

Thanks,
Murali

Answer (score 1):

Here we fristly check the ur path. when ur path is correctly. Then after u will move the given location (their checking jvm.dll file will be presented or not).
that type problem came max to max 64-bit systems.

Here main focus on path. when u set path then after retsart the system.

Answer (score 0):

This happend to me yesterday and fortunately I found this post.
I was working on eclipse and tried to compile a class using the command line in paralell. I noticed that the javac command wasn't on the Path environment variable so I added.
Afterwards, I closed Eclipse and when I tried restarting the IDE I found the "*Failed to load JNI shared Library*" error.
I opened back the environment variable dialog box and pointed the java bin path to a compatible version of java (Same bit version on both, eclipse and jdk).
Finally I was able to start eclipse again.