# How to see my Eclipse version?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

How do I find out which version of Eclipse is currently installed on my system?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604869/finding-the-eclipse-version-number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the Eclipse Version Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604869/finding-the-eclipse-version-number)

Answer (score 29):

Open `.eclipseproduct` in the product installation folder. Or open `Configuration\config.ini` and check property `eclipse.buildId` if exist.

Comment: `eclipse.buildId=debbuild` :/ Found under *Help -> About Eclipse Platform*.

Answer (score 20):

`Help -> About Eclipse Platform`

For Eclipse Mars - you can check `Eclipse -> About Eclipse` or `Help -> Installation Details`, then you should see the version:

[image]

Comment: no such option found. Help -> About (which has many buttons but no version info)

Comment: In eclipse 4.2 I found the version name in readme file placed inside android bundle

Answer (score 13):

Go to `Help -> About Eclipse Sdk`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Go to the folder in which eclipse is installed then open readme folder followed by the readme txt file. Here you will find all the info you need.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can find out Eclipse Platform version for every software product that is Eclipse-based.

1. Open **Installation Details**:

   - Go to Help => About => Installation Details.
   - Or to Help => Install New Software... => click **What is already installed?** link.
2. Choose **Plug-ins** tab => type *org.eclipse.platform* => check **Version** column.
3. You can match version code and version name on https://wiki.eclipse.org/Older_Versions_Of_Eclipse

For example, check out GitEye (Git GUI client)
[image: GitEye Installation Details]

Or  checkout DBBeaver (DB manager):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Same issue i was getting , but When we open our eclipse software then automatically we can see eclipse version and workspace location like these pic below 
[image]