# Eclipse : how to find out the Eclipse Version

Tags: eclipse

Could anybody please tell me how to find out the Eclipse Version i am using .

This is basically , i need to download a Software for Eclipse which says if its (lesser than ) <=3.5 download one link and if its (greater than ) > = 3.6

I tried to find out the Eclipse version this way

From Eclipse Menu **Help ----> About Eclipse**

It displayed as

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110218-0911
```

But i am not sure if its greater or lesser than 3.5

Comment: have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604869/finding-the-eclipse-version-number)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

eclipse has a file `.eclipseproduct` in its root folder which contains its version.
When you open the file it will look likes

```
name=Eclipse Platform
id=org.eclipse.platform
version=3.7.0
```

Comment: A very effective way to hide the version information :)

Comment: No such exists in my Ubuntu. :/

Answer (score 2):

Helios releases were 3.6.X (there is a list of the matchup between version names and numbers on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29)).

Though if there isn't any specific reason for using a release that old you may wish to update. Helios won't be supported much longer.