# FAILED to open .js extension files in Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, cordova

I am devloping phonegap application using eclipse whenever  i am trying to open .js extension files it by default open "Alert"  of Adobe DreamViewer and my adobe has been expired so its show me "Adobe Alert do u want to buy ? "  Moreover its not opening any .js file and when i am trying to open file by 
    rightclick---->open with ----->TextEditor
   then there is only code appearing in editor no "Code Completion "  appears no error indication ....nothing how can i resolve this issue ?

here is the result after following answer.....
when trying to open file i am getting "The Class File Viewer cannot handle the given input."  in Editor .Snapshots added 
   [image: Js settings]
when opening file then: 
    [image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to install javascript editor plugin for eclipse. Follow the link below to do it:

[JavaScript Editor Plugin for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269560/javascript-editor-plugin-for-eclipse)

Comment: how can i know which version of eclipse i have installed in my system and how can i give url in eclipse ?

Comment: for version see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604869/finding-the-eclipse-version-number.

Comment: Follow the steps mentioned. Once you go to Help tab->Install new software, you will get option to give URL

Comment: snapshots added can u please see it

Comment: Are you trying for the right version of eclipse that is installed on your system?

Comment: i think i am doing something wrong here because still i am unable to open file by double click on it and as well as its not working for ctrl+click on any method

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48025/discussion-between-user3233280-and-sushil)